# How to copy a table from one DB to another using a single query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, copy, information-schema

Recently, a friend asked me this question.

**Is it possible to copy an entire table(structure and data) from one database to another using a single query?**
(Not the `export whole table` option)

I said: *YES!- knowing very well that there will be a better option for doing this.*

Then I started looking for it. And myself wrote a simple code from my limited knowlege in working with things like `information_schema`.

My Syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE new_db.new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_db_name.old_table);
```

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE test.db
      AS (SELECT * FROM mysql.db);
```

I am surprised-that the query execution was successful.

> USE `information_schema`; CREATE TABLE test.db
>         AS (SELECT * FROM mysql.db); /* Affected rows: 2  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.484 sec. */ USE `test`;

But I can't see any changes there in the `test` database.

I have searched for this and still don't find any perfect answer for this. Or let me know why this is not possible?

Comment: I don't know mysql very well, but why at the first line of the script there is "USE information_schema" and not "USE test" (that is the database where you want create the table)?

Comment: Okay. is it possible to retrieve a table from database `mysql` if `use test`?

Comment: If the purpose is to copy only one table you can execute something like this: 
CREATE TABLE <dst_db>.table_clone AS (SELECT * FROM <src_db>.source_table);

Comment: do you want to copy data from one database to the other database?